# Direct (inductive) limit of groups

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $(I,\prec)$ be a directed poset and $\{G_i\}_{i \in I}$ groups with group homomorphisms $f_{ij}:G_i \to G_j$ whenever $i \prec j$. Is is true that the direct limit of this system is given by 
$$
 G := \left (\bigsqcup_{i \in I} G_i \right ) / \sim
$$ where $(g,i) \sim (h,j)$ if and only if there exists a $i,j \prec k$ with $f_{ik}(g) = f_{jk}(h)$. The multiplication is given by 
$$
 [(g,i)][(h,j)] = [f_{ik}(g) f_{jk}(g)]
$$ for $i,j \prec k$. It can be checked that all of this is well defined.

I did the same construction for modules over a ring and hence also for abelian groups and rings.

My question: Is $G$ indeed a group (also when the $G_i$ are not assumed to be abelian) and hence a directed limit of the given system ?

Comment: Is $f_{ij}f_{jk} = f_{ik}$ when this makes sense?

Comment: Also, I think you need an extra condition on $(I, \prec)$ so that your $k$ in the definition of the multiplication exists.

Comment: Yes, everything is functorial and each pair $i,j$ has an upper bound. Furthermore I would write rather $f_{jk} f_{ij} = f_{ik}$, than $f_{ij}f_{jk} = f_{ik}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is straight forward to check the group axioms; they are inherited from the $G_i$. This construction can be found in *every* book which treats direct limits (which is the wrong name for directed colimits) and of course [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit).

Comment: Which meaning has  "directed colimit" ?

Comment: A colimit indexed by a directed category. One also speaks of filtered colimits. It is important to distinguish these from limits, that's why the classical terminology of "direct limits" is very unfortunate and should be avoided, in my opinion.

Comment: Is a filtered category the same as a directed category ? And have categories which correspond to a directed poset (poset with finite upper bounds) a special name ?

Comment: is "inverse limit" okay then?